# Tomcat 7.0.25 apr jre crash

Tags: jvm, tomcat7, jvm-crash

I just upgraded from tomcat 6.0.29 to 7.0.25 using native apr.

Tomcat has crashed a few times with the report below.

None of it means much to me other than that the crash seemed to happen when using zip, which is could be to do with the gzip setting to compress certain file types.

I couldn't find any other references anywhere with this issue, and when I looked at the changelog from 7.0.25 to 7.0.26 no mention was made of fixing any issues like this.

Any advice/help/solutions welcome.

Thanks.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000739a576c, pid=2504, tid=3792
#
# JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0x576c]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\bin\hs_err_pid2504.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000089e9000):  JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-32" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3792, stack(0x0000000019400000,0x0000000019500000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000000909f000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000009056110, RBX=0x0000000012dc1020, RCX=0x0000000000048ef0, RDX=0x0000000009d2a290
RSP=0x00000000194fe710, RBP=0x0000000000000004, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000048eee, R10=0x4b0c4ed76a743daf, R11=0x00000007c260d3c0
R12=0x0000000000008eec, R13=0x0000000000000003, R14=0x0000000000000002, R15=0x0000000000000002
RIP=0x00000000739a576c, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010286

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000194fe710)
0x00000000194fe710:   00000000089e91d0 00000000739a4262
0x00000000194fe720:   0000000000000024 0000000069fa4915
0x00000000194fe730:   0000000000000001 00000000ffffffff
0x00000000194fe740:   000000000000029a 00000000739a49ae
0x00000000194fe750:   0000000012dc1020 0000000000000004
0x00000000194fe760:   0000000013241630 0000000000000000
0x00000000194fe770:   0000000000000200 0000000000002301
0x00000000194fe780:   00000007c260d600 0000000008c42580
0x00000000194fe790:   0000000000000000 00000000739a16df
0x00000000194fe7a0:   00000000089e91d0 00000000194fe848
0x00000000194fe7b0:   0000000013241630 0000000755fe5e48
0x00000000194fe7c0:   0000000755fe5d38 0000000755fe5d68
0x00000000194fe7d0:   00000000089e9000 0000000000002328
0x00000000194fe7e0:   0000000755fe5e48 0000000000000000
0x00000000194fe7f0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000200
0x00000000194fe800:   00000000194fe880 0000000002715bbc 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000739a576c)
0x00000000739a574c:   85 c0 0f 84 d9 03 00 00 41 3b c5 72 69 48 8b 43
0x00000000739a575c:   50 44 8b 8b 94 00 00 00 48 8b 53 68 41 8d 49 02
0x00000000739a576c:   44 0f b6 04 01 8b 43 70 8b 8b 80 00 00 00 d3 e0
0x00000000739a577c:   48 8b 4b 60 44 33 c0 8b 43 4c 44 23 43 7c 4c 23 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000009056110 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000012dc1020 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000048ef0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000009d2a290 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000194fe710 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000089e9000
RBP=0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000048eee is an unknown value
R10=0x4b0c4ed76a743daf is an unknown value
R11=0x00000007c260d3c0 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000008eec is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000019400000,0x0000000019500000],  sp=0x00000000194fe710,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [zip.dll+0x576c]  ZIP_Open+0x1690

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BIII)I
J  java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish()V
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.finish()V+9
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.end()J+26
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close()V
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.close()V+4
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+457
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
j  org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RewrittenUrl.doRewrite(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)Z+110
j  org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+289
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+196
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;
J  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000009bc0000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-90" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3868, stack(0x000000001c680000,0x000000001c780000)]
  0x0000000009bbf000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-89" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3396, stack(0x000000001c530000,0x000000001c630000)]
  0x0000000009bbe800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-88" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5560, stack(0x000000001bd10000,0x000000001be10000)]
  0x0000000009bbd800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-87" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5900, stack(0x000000001a2e0000,0x000000001a3e0000)]
  0x0000000009bbd000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-86" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4708, stack(0x000000001c420000,0x000000001c520000)]
  0x0000000009bbc000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-85" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2408, stack(0x000000001c1d0000,0x000000001c2d0000)]
  0x0000000009bbb800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-84" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1864, stack(0x000000001c010000,0x000000001c110000)]
  0x0000000009c22800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-83" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5280, stack(0x000000001be30000,0x000000001bf30000)]
  0x0000000009c22000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-82" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5624, stack(0x000000001ba70000,0x000000001bb70000)]
  0x0000000009c21800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-81" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5812, stack(0x000000001bc10000,0x000000001bd10000)]
  0x0000000009c20800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-80" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4076, stack(0x000000001b820000,0x000000001b920000)]
  0x0000000009c20000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-79" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=260, stack(0x000000001b960000,0x000000001ba60000)]
  0x0000000009c1f000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-78" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5868, stack(0x000000001b6a0000,0x000000001b7a0000)]
  0x0000000009c1e800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-77" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1748, stack(0x000000001b3d0000,0x000000001b4d0000)]
  0x0000000009c1d800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-76" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6000, stack(0x000000001b510000,0x000000001b610000)]
  0x0000000009c1d000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-75" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4028, stack(0x000000001acf0000,0x000000001adf0000)]
  0x0000000009c1c000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-74" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5540, stack(0x000000001b240000,0x000000001b340000)]
  0x0000000009c1b800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-73" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5920, stack(0x000000001a0b0000,0x000000001a1b0000)]
  0x000000000b4a2000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-72" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5164, stack(0x000000001b0f0000,0x000000001b1f0000)]
  0x000000000b4a1000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-71" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4544, stack(0x00000000110d0000,0x00000000111d0000)]
  0x000000000b4a0800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-70" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4236, stack(0x000000001afd0000,0x000000001b0d0000)]
  0x000000000b49f800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-69" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5012, stack(0x000000001adf0000,0x000000001aef0000)]
  0x000000000b49f000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-68" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2808, stack(0x000000001a600000,0x000000001a700000)]
  0x000000000b49e000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-67" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3112, stack(0x000000001aba0000,0x000000001aca0000)]
  0x000000000b49d800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-66" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2512, stack(0x000000001aa70000,0x000000001ab70000)]
  0x000000000b49d000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-65" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2184, stack(0x000000001a970000,0x000000001aa70000)]
  0x000000000b49c000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-64" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4912, stack(0x000000001a840000,0x000000001a940000)]
  0x000000000b49b800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-63" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3704, stack(0x000000001a700000,0x000000001a800000)]
  0x000000000b49a800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-62" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5352, stack(0x000000001a4f0000,0x000000001a5f0000)]
  0x00000000089e7000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-61" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5744, stack(0x000000001a3f0000,0x000000001a4f0000)]
  0x00000000098af800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-60" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5604, stack(0x000000001a1e0000,0x000000001a2e0000)]
  0x0000000008de6800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-59" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1052, stack(0x0000000019f80000,0x000000001a080000)]
  0x0000000008dea800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-58" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2332, stack(0x0000000019ce0000,0x0000000019de0000)]
  0x0000000008de8000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-57" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4608, stack(0x0000000017bb0000,0x0000000017cb0000)]
  0x0000000008de9000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-56" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5772, stack(0x0000000012a40000,0x0000000012b40000)]
  0x0000000009498800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-55" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4008, stack(0x0000000019a90000,0x0000000019b90000)]
  0x000000000949a800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-54" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5852, stack(0x0000000019e00000,0x0000000019f00000)]
  0x000000000949f000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-53" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1260, stack(0x0000000019ba0000,0x0000000019ca0000)]
  0x000000000949c800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-52" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4816, stack(0x0000000019980000,0x0000000019a80000)]
  0x0000000009fde800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-51" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4572, stack(0x00000000190a0000,0x00000000191a0000)]
  0x0000000009fd9800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-50" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6056, stack(0x0000000019560000,0x0000000019660000)]
  0x0000000009fdf000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-49" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4456, stack(0x0000000018e30000,0x0000000018f30000)]
  0x0000000009fda000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-48" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3568, stack(0x0000000018f30000,0x0000000019030000)]
  0x0000000009fda800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-47" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5616, stack(0x0000000017ab0000,0x0000000017bb0000)]
  0x000000000b4c2000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-46" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5184, stack(0x000000000f420000,0x000000000f520000)]
  0x000000000b4c1000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-45" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1280, stack(0x0000000015990000,0x0000000015a90000)]
  0x000000000b4c0800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-44" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5172, stack(0x000000000de80000,0x000000000df80000)]
  0x000000000b4bf800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-43" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2656, stack(0x00000000154d0000,0x00000000155d0000)]
  0x000000000b4bf000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-42" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5436, stack(0x0000000014260000,0x0000000014360000)]
  0x000000000b4be000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-41" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3660, stack(0x0000000013f50000,0x0000000014050000)]
  0x000000000b4bd800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-40" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1200, stack(0x0000000013d60000,0x0000000013e60000)]
  0x000000000b4bd000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-39" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5528, stack(0x0000000012930000,0x0000000012a30000)]
  0x000000000b4ba800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-38" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3808, stack(0x000000000fef0000,0x000000000fff0000)]
  0x000000000949e000 JavaThread "Thread-87" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2140, stack(0x0000000011370000,0x0000000011470000)]
  0x000000000949b000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4604, stack(0x000000000e140000,0x000000000e240000)]
  0x000000000949c000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-37" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1380, stack(0x000000000dfc0000,0x000000000e0c0000)]
=>0x00000000089e9000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-32" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3792, stack(0x0000000019400000,0x0000000019500000)]
  0x0000000009fe0000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-31" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4196, stack(0x0000000019260000,0x0000000019360000)]
  0x0000000009fdd800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-28" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3416, stack(0x0000000014140000,0x0000000014240000)]
  0x0000000009fdd000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-27" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5372, stack(0x0000000013b20000,0x0000000013c20000)]
  0x0000000009fdc000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-26" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=756, stack(0x00000000157b0000,0x00000000158b0000)]
  0x0000000009fdb800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3500, stack(0x0000000018ce0000,0x0000000018de0000)]
  0x0000000009fd8800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-24" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3312, stack(0x0000000015600000,0x0000000015700000)]
  0x0000000009499800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5792, stack(0x0000000015370000,0x0000000015470000)]
  0x00000000089e8800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-21" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5348, stack(0x0000000013c30000,0x0000000013d30000)]
  0x0000000009499000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-15" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1016, stack(0x000000000a360000,0x000000000a460000)]
  0x0000000009497800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-13" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3952, stack(0x00000000127c0000,0x00000000128c0000)]
  0x00000000098b3800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-12" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4452, stack(0x0000000011630000,0x0000000011730000)]
  0x00000000098b2800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-11" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5472, stack(0x0000000011530000,0x0000000011630000)]
  0x00000000098b1000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3688, stack(0x000000000a460000,0x000000000a560000)]
  0x00000000098b0800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4764, stack(0x000000000e810000,0x000000000e910000)]
  0x00000000098af000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x00000000111d0000,0x00000000112d0000)]
  0x00000000098ae800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3772, stack(0x0000000010fd0000,0x00000000110d0000)]
  0x00000000098ad800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3936, stack(0x0000000010e30000,0x0000000010f30000)]
  0x00000000098ad000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4256, stack(0x000000000fa80000,0x000000000fb80000)]
  0x00000000098ac000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3240, stack(0x0000000010cd0000,0x0000000010dd0000)]
  0x00000000089e9800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3108, stack(0x0000000010b20000,0x0000000010c20000)]
  0x00000000089e7800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-exec-10" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2676, stack(0x000000000ed30000,0x000000000ee30000)]
  0x00000000089e6000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x00000000101e0000,0x00000000102e0000)]
  0x00000000089e5800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4804, stack(0x000000000fdb0000,0x000000000feb0000)]
  0x00000000089e4800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2556, stack(0x000000000fbc0000,0x000000000fcc0000)]
  0x00000000089e4000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3820, stack(0x000000000f970000,0x000000000fa70000)]
  0x00000000089e3000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2528, stack(0x000000000f850000,0x000000000f950000)]
  0x00000000089e2800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3748, stack(0x000000000f6e0000,0x000000000f7e0000)]
  0x00000000089e2000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1936, stack(0x000000000f520000,0x000000000f620000)]
  0x00000000089e1000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5028, stack(0x000000000f310000,0x000000000f410000)]
  0x00000000089e0800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5672, stack(0x000000000f090000,0x000000000f190000)]
  0x00000000089df800 JavaThread "http-apr-443-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3224, stack(0x000000000f1c0000,0x000000000f2c0000)]
  0x00000000089df000 JavaThread "http-apr-443-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked,       0x0000000008de1800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5124, stack(0x000000000d5b0000,0x000000000d6b0000)]
  0x0000000008de1000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4944, stack(0x000000000cf30000,0x000000000d030000)]
  0x0000000008de0000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4924, stack(0x000000000d040000,0x000000000d140000)]
  0x0000000008ddf800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2076, stack(0x000000000c910000,0x000000000ca10000)]


Other Threads:
  0x0000000001f0b000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000007530000,0x0000000007630000] [id=4292]
  0x00000000070d5800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000007960000,0x0000000007a60000] [id=2920]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 1037952K, used 70503K [0x00000007c0000000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 1026688K, 6% used [0x00000007c0000000,0x00000007c406a560,0x00000007feaa0000)
  from space 11264K, 40% used [0x00000007ff500000,0x00000007ff96f770,0x0000000800000000)
  to   space 10624K, 0% used [0x00000007feaa0000,0x00000007feaa0000,0x00000007ff500000)
 PSOldGen        total 2097152K, used 430155K [0x0000000740000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  object space 2097152K, 20% used [0x0000000740000000,0x000000075a412ce8,0x00000007c0000000)
 PSPermGen       total 88768K, used 47835K [0x0000000680000000, 0x00000006856b0000, 0x0000000740000000)
  object space 88768K, 53% used [0x0000000680000000,0x0000000682eb6eb8,0x00000006856b0000)

Code Cache  [0x00000000020e0000, 0x00000000029f0000, 0x00000000050e0000)
 total_blobs=2605 nmethods=1994 adapters=562 free_code_cache=39996Kb largest_free_block=40849792

Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f360000 - 0x000000013f393000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java.exe
0x0000000076d40000 - 0x0000000076eec000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076c20000 - 0x0000000076d3f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd000000 - 0x000007fefd06b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefef70000 - 0x000007feff04b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefe6c0000 - 0x000007fefe75f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefd680000 - 0x000007fefd69f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe8d0000 - 0x000007fefe9fe000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076b20000 - 0x0000000076c1a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefef00000 - 0x000007fefef67000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefd6a0000 - 0x000007fefd6ae000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefee30000 - 0x000007fefeefa000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb740000 - 0x000007fefb934000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16661_none_fa62ad231704eab7\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefea00000 - 0x000007fefea71000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefd730000 - 0x000007fefd75e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefe760000 - 0x000007fefe869000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000073030000 - 0x0000000073101000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000069eb0000 - 0x000000006a58a000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef97b0000 - 0x000007fef97b9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefe880000 - 0x000007fefe8cd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefe870000 - 0x000007fefe878000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fef97c0000 - 0x000007fef97fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000076f10000 - 0x0000000076f17000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000073c00000 - 0x0000000073c0f000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073bd0000 - 0x0000000073bf8000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00000000739a0000 - 0x00000000739b5000     C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00000000739c0000 - 0x00000000739d9000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc4d0000 - 0x000007fefc524000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc4c0000 - 0x000007fefc4c7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000073410000 - 0x0000000073421000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000073c10000 - 0x0000000073c1b000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\management.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x0000000010125000     C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\bin\tcnative-1.dll
0x000007fefc530000 - 0x000007fefc547000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc230000 - 0x000007fefc277000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcb90000 - 0x000007fefcb9f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000072f70000 - 0x0000000072f94000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x000000006de80000 - 0x000000006de8b000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefcdf0000 - 0x000007fefcf56000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcd40000 - 0x000007fefcd4f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefbed0000 - 0x000007fefbed7000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefbfe0000 - 0x000007fefbffe000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefcca0000 - 0x000007fefccaf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefb620000 - 0x000007fefb635000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fefc350000 - 0x000007fefc3ab000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef9780000 - 0x000007fef978b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef9760000 - 0x000007fef9775000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefa520000 - 0x000007fefa547000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa510000 - 0x000007fefa51b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9200000 - 0x000007fef9208000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa360000 - 0x000007fefa3b3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006d7f0000 - 0x000000006d820000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x000000006c680000 - 0x000000006c814000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefec90000 - 0x000007fefed67000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefea80000 - 0x000007fefec82000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000000006d500000 - 0x000000006d5a2000     C:\java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\mlib_image.dll
0x000007fefaff0000 - 0x000007fefb115000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=3072m -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dlog4j.configuration=logger.properties -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25 -Dcatalina.home=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
JRE_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
CLASSPATH=C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\production\Tomcat-7.0.25\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
PATH=C:\app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
USERNAME=***
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7600 

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 11, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 8387032k(487964k free), swap 16772168k(9441420k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_02-b13), built on Nov 17 2011 13:51:15 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Fri Mar 16 15:16:36 2012
elapsed time: 11112 seconds
```

Comment: I have disabled compression in my server.xml until I get a chance to move to 7.0.26 unless I can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JVM bug in the zip compression. It (or something very like it) has been seen before [1]. Disabling compression is really the only option until Oracle fix the bug. If you have a simple test case that reproduces the issue then it would be worth opening up a bug report.

[1] http://tomcat.markmail.org/thread/ar2r7qop7n76hsgi

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this with Tomcat 7.0.47 / Java 1.7 and Tomcat 7.0.55 / Java 8

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb65d73a4, pid=5872, tid=1834171200
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x83a4]  deflate_slow+0x44


# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa80506bdcd, pid=1463, tid=140358692861696
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x4dcd]  deflate_slow+0x3d
```

It appears to be data dependent, but I didn't have the time to try to figure it out. I "solved" issue this by disabling compression in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I also got crashed tomcat enabling compression.

```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

con/server.xml

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
     compression="on" 
     compressionMinSize="2048" 
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/javascript"
/>
```

crash report.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa902990c14, pid=10845, tid=140362698929920
#
# JRE version: 6.0_31-b31
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libz.so.1+0x4c14]  uncompress+0x774
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fa844010800):  JavaThread "http-bio-80-exec-87" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=27442, stack(0x00007fa8bcbf3000,0x00007fa8bccf4000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x00007fa7c0055000

...........
...........

Stack: [0x00007fa8bcbf3000,0x00007fa8bccf4000],  sp=0x00007fa8bccf0110,  free space=1012k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libz.so.1+0x4c14]  uncompress+0x774

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(J[BII)I
J  java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate([BII)I
j  java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.finish()V+41
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.finish()V+9
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.end()J+26
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.endRequest()V+43
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest()V+1
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+124
j  org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+31
j  org.apache.coyote.Response.finish()V+5
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close()V+138
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.close()V+4
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+467
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+55
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+244
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+157
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+225
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+388
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+219
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+10
j  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+446
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+40
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+76
j  org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(Lorg/springframework/security/intercept/web/FilterInvocation;)V+87
j  org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+15
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+93
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+3
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+148
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+86
j  org.joget.apps.workflow.security.WorkflowHttpAuthProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+49
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.joget.apps.workflow.controller.WorkflowBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+532
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+120
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+180
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+134
j  org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+44
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+199
j  org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+165
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Ljavax/servlet/Filter;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+5
j  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+75
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+59
j  org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+90
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+783
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+166
j  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+449
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+158
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+196
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+632
j  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+270
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+130
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```